# Check if jquery plugin is loaded

Tags: jquery, jquery-backstretch

How can I check if this jquery plugin backstrech was already loaded:
http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-backstretch/2.0.4/jquery.backstretch.min.js

`if($.fn.backstretch)` is not working.

Comment: Looks about right. How is it *"not working"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it works to me.

[Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/37Nta/1/)

```
backstretch_src = "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/" +
                  "jquery-backstretch/2.0.4/jquery.backstretch.min.js";

$(function init() {
    updateStatus();
    $('head').append($('<script>').attr('src', backstretch_src));
    setTimeout(updateStatus, 1000);
});

function updateStatus() {
    $('#status').text($.fn.backstretch ? 'Loaded' : 'Not loaded');
}
```